# iDangero.us Swiper & React - dealing with dynamic data

Tags: jquery, slider, reactjs, swiper.js

I have a question related to implementation of iDangero.us Swiper with React. I have been playing with it for a while and my problem is that the actual sliding doesn't work in situation when I work with dynamic data. Let me illustrate this on example.

My code is composed in following way:

1) I have a component called SwiperComponent. There are two parts - method componentDidMount() where I put the initialisation of the Swiper component and render() one where I generate the structure defined by iDangero.us Swiper.

```
var SwiperComponent = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount() {
    this.swipe = new Swiper(React.findDOMNode(this), {
      slidesPerView: 3,
      centeredSlides: true,
      spaceBetween: 10
    });
  },

  render() {
    return React.createElement('div', React.__spread({}, this.props, {className: 'swiper-container'}),
      React.createElement('div', {className: 'swiper-wrapper'},
        React.Children.map(this.props.children, function (child, index) {
          return React.createElement('div', {className: 'swiper-slide'}, React.cloneElement(child));
       })
      )
    );
  }
});
```

2) I have a simple Index.jsx file where I prepare a 'dynamic content' in a way that I simply create an array which I populate with some images.

```
var Index = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      movies: []
    };
  },

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      movies: ["http://www.themusehotel.com/design/images/930-481/nyc-skyline.jpg", "https://ephemeralnewyork.files.wordpress.com/2010/08/broadway47thstreet2010.jpg", "http://41.media.tumblr.com/27d14da3be1e02eb7b6ead5bda0ac1b2/tumblr_n5dqi4XDz61qdeuyro1_1280.jpg", "http://photos.cntraveler.com/2014/09/29/5429c32b425f183f61bf7316_new-york-city-skyline.jpg"],
    });
  },


  render: function() {
    var items = this.state.movies;

    return (
      <SwiperComponent>
      {
        items.map((item) => {
          return (
           <img src={item} width="100%" height="200"/>
          )
        })
      }
      </SwiperComponent>
    )
  }
});
```

As I mentioned, the problem is that the sliding part doesn't work. Quite interesting thing is that it starts working once I open the developer console in Chrome or swipe out the array and place some static tags instead of.

I prepare a JSfiddle where you can see this problem in action - https://jsfiddle.net/4z3zyk07/4/

Does anybody know what I have been missing and doing wrong? I will appreciate your help a lot. Thank you very much!

Radek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you use **this.setState** to fill your array movies in the life cycle of `"componentDidMount"`

when outer componentDidMount is called, the inner componentDidMount is already called,and at this time your Swiper doesn't find any of the pictures thus it can't calculate a right width for every image.

Initialize your picture data in componentWillMount.

```
  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
      movies: [your pictures],
    });
  },
```

then Swiper will know how many images are in the box and calculate a width for everyone.